# unable to load webengine.dll in visual studio 2005

Tags: c#

I have one problem in my application while i built my application it shows error like unable to load WebEngine.dll  please guide me.

Unable to load DLL 'webengine.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from `HRESULT: 0x8007007E`) /

Comment: Did you compile an ASP.NET project and receive this error on Windows Vista and above? Did you configure this project to use local IIS? If so, try to set the application pool to classic mode and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This will likely be becausee the dll is in the wrong location or becuas of a dependency of the WebEngine dll. Look in the Output window after trying to compile to get some more detail or in the Errors window for warnings and error messages.